# identical value in foreach get deleted

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem with my following code. Even if I try to make it work in a WordPress template, I decided to post it here cause I think it's a PHP related error in my code.

So, here is my code. Everything is going well with it, it display contributors on a page by alphabetical value or their family name. The problem is when the 'family_name' **meta_key** output two identical values, one of the two (or more) get deleted or are missing from my output. I search and tried many things but I still can't find a solution to this. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
$terms = get_terms(array(
    'taxonomy' => 'contributors',
    'meta_key' => 'letter_group',
    'meta_value' => 'a'));

$order_terms = array();

foreach( $terms as $term ) {
    $position = get_field('family_name', $term);
    $order_terms[$position] ='<a href="'. get_bloginfo( 'url' ) . '/contributors/' . $term->slug . '">'.$term->name.'</a><br>';
}

ksort($order_terms);
foreach( $order_terms as $order_term ) {
    echo $order_term;}

wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: where do you get $position?

Comment: @Dimi first line in the first loop, apparently. Francois, I don't understand much about WordPress but to debug this you can do the usual routine...if you `print_r` your arrays, and echo variables one at a time do you get what you expect to get? Where exactly is the problem happening?

Comment: @sidyll my bad, was staring at the code for too long today. ~_~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the things that you can do is make it an array instead

```
foreach( $terms as $term ) {
    $position = get_field('family_name', $term);
    $order_terms[$position][] ='<a href="'. get_bloginfo( 'url' ) . '/contributors/' . $term->slug . '">'.$term->name.'</a><br>';
}
```

then print them out as a nested array

```
foreach( $order_terms as $a ) {
     foreach($a as $order_term)
    echo $order_term;}
```

Comment: This is precisely what is happening, `$position` is family name so when the family name is the same it overwrites the previous entry. I don't fancy the nested array though. I think that `$position` can be eliminated completely, and just use `$order_terms[] ='<a href...a><br>';` inside the loop. The keys will be numeric but whatever, they aren't used anyway. What do you think?

Comment: hmm. I like it. in that case ksort($order_terms); will need to be replaced with asort($order_terms) and everything will work.

Comment: Ach, I hadn't noticed that he was using last name for the sort. I think asort wouldn't be the same then, it would sort by `$term->slug` then, right? We both starring at code too long today :D

Comment: Keep the nested array

Comment: Thanks @Dimi and @sidyll. In fact, if I remove the `$position`, they are all outputted on my page, but their ordering is wrong. The 'family_name' value is not used anymore.

Comment: @francois replace family_name with anything worthy of being ordered on, and it should work.

Comment: @francois yes, initially I didn't noticed you used it to sort. The nested array solution Dimi used here should work though. Either this or another form of nested array, like `[ [name, link], [name, link] ]` and then `usort` with a custom function to sort it.

Comment: @sidyll : "replace family_name with anything worthy of being ordered on" : I unfortunately can't. Many of those contributors has multiple 'first name' so I had to create that field so we know which one is the family name.

Comment: @francois I see. And have you tried the solution Dimi posted here? Wouldn't it work?

Comment: @sidyll I will try it now. Back to you with the result.

Comment: Yes, it finally work like a charm, thanks so much @Dimi, you save my life on this :-)

Comment: And thanks for your help @sidyll. Viva StackOverflow!